# Why can't I call this constructor with two arguments in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm learning about scope. Just making a simple program to calculate the length of a line based on the coordinates of the two endpoints in the line. In line 7 of the code below I am getting a compiler error saying that the constructor of the Line class cannot take two arguments. Why is that? And then at around line 30 and 31 I cannot get the GetLength method to recognize the bottomRight point and the origin point. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

```
class Program
{
    static void doWork()
    {
        Point origin = new Point(0,0);
        Point bottomRight = new Point(1366, 768);
        Line myLine = new Line(bottomRight, origin);
        //double distance = origin.DistanceTo(bottomRight);
        double distance = GetLength(myLine);
        Console.WriteLine("Distance is: {0}", distance);
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Point objects: {0}", Point.ObjectCount());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            doWork();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static double GetLength(Line line)
    {
        Point pointA = line.bottomRight;
        Point pointB = line.origin;
        return pointA.DistanceTo(pointB);
    }

}

class Line
{

    static void Line(Point pointA, Point pointB)
    {
        pointA = new Point();
        pointB = new Point();
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the Point class:

```
class Point
{
    private int x, y;
    private static int objectCount = 0;

    public Point()
    {
        this.x = -1;
        this.y = -1;
        objectCount++;
    }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        objectCount++;
    }

    public double DistanceTo(Point other)
    {
        int xDiff = this.x - other.x;
        int yDiff = this.y - other.y;
        double distance = Math.Sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));
        return distance;
    }

    public static int ObjectCount()
    {
        return objectCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: look at your definition of Line class. There are no backing variables....

Comment: `static void Line(Point pointA, Point pointB)` is not a constructor. Change the `static void` to `public`.

Comment: You haven't defined any constructors for `Line`.  So it only has a default one with no parameters.  Thus, there's no constructor with two parameters.  It also has no members called `bottomRight` or `origin`, so you can't access members that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use void

```
 public Line(Point pointA, Point pointB)
    {
        pointA = new Point();
        pointB = new Point();
    }
```

Comment: I fixed the constructor by removing the "static void" with "public", but now I'm having a problem with the GetLength method. I can't get that method to recognize the two variables inside the Line myLine object, bottomRight and origin. How can i access those?

Comment: @shampouya I don't mean to be rude, but I'm going to say that you're going to run into many problems while programming this, and it may be more beneficial to do a crash course in C# development rather than live debugging/learning an app on SO.

Comment: I'm actually 7 days into a crash course in C# development at the moment. This is our first class exercise that I'm trying to work through. Does anyone know how I can access Point variables within the myLine object in my program?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Line` class looks incomplete. It doesn't store any data. It should looks more like this:

```
class Line
{
    public Point BottomRight { get; set; }
    public Point Origin { get; set; }

    public Line(Point pointA, Point pointB)
    {
        Origin = pointA;
        BottomRight = pointB;
    }
}
```

Then you need to only change `line.BottomRight` and `line.Origin` in `GetLength` method:

```
    static double GetLength(Line line)
    {
        Point pointA = line.BottomRight;
        Point pointB = line.Origin;
        return pointA.DistanceTo(pointB);
    }
```

This should work now

Comment: @shampouya You're welcome:) but you should consider accepting answers instead of comments. Looking at your profile, I'm not sure You're aware of that practice:)